# How to deserialize a UDPTunnel in protobuf.net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, unityscript

I'm doing a voip client code with mumble in Unity3d (c# scripting) and now I'm able to successfully connect to any of mumble public server. But when I try to deserialize a UDP tunnel I get a lot of exceptions including 'invalid wiretype', 'number overflow', 'invalid field', 'endofstream', 'wrong group was ended' and bla bla... all of the at this particular line.

```
var udpTunnel = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<UDPTunnel> (_ssl, PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
```

where _ssl is SslStream

Here is my complete method

```
nternal void ProcessTcpData ()
{
        try {

                var masg = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder (_reader.ReadInt16 ());
                MessageType messageType = (MessageType)masg;
                Debug.Log ("Received message type: " + messageType);

                switch (messageType) {
                case MessageType.Version:
                        _mc.RemoteVersion = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Version> (_ssl,
PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        break;
                case MessageType.CryptSetup:
                        var cryptSetup = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<CryptSetup> (_ssl,
PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        ProcessCryptSetup (cryptSetup);
                        break;
                case MessageType.CodecVersion:
                        _mc.CodecVersion = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<CodecVersion> (_ssl,
PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        break;
                case MessageType.ChannelState:
                        _mc.ChannelState = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<ChannelState> (_ssl,
PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        break;
                case MessageType.PermissionQuery:
                        _mc.PermissionQuery = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<PermissionQuery> (_ssl,
PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        break;
                case MessageType.UserState:
                        _mc.UserState = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<UserState> (_ssl,
PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        break;
                case MessageType.ServerSync:
                        _mc.ServerSync = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<ServerSync> (_ssl,
PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        _mc.ConnectionSetupFinished = true;
                        break;
                case MessageType.ServerConfig:
                        _mc.ServerConfig = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<ServerConfig> (_ssl,
PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        _validConnection = true; // handshake complete
                        break;
                case MessageType.TextMessage:
                        var textMessage = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<TextMessage> (_ssl, PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        break;
                case MessageType.UDPTunnel:
                        if (_validConnection) {
                                var udpTunnel = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<UDPTunnel> (_ssl, PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        }
                        break;
                case MessageType.Ping:
                        var ping = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<MumbleProto.Ping> (_ssl, PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        Debug.Log ("Received ping: " + ping.timestamp + ", udp: " + ping.udp_packets + ", tcp:" +
                                ping.tcp_packets);
                        break;
                case MessageType.Reject:
                        var reject = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Reject> (_ssl,
PrefixStyle.Fixed32BigEndian);
                        _validConnection = false;
                        _errorCallback ("Mumble server reject: " + reject.reason, true);
                        break;
                default:
                        _errorCallback ("Message type " + messageType + " not implemented", true);
                        break;
                }
                if (_validConnection) {
                        Debug.Log ("Handshake Complete:\tconnection is valid");
                }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.LogException (ex);
        }
}
```

_reader is a BinaryReader

Comment: Are you getting back the same bytes that you sent? Until you know you are getting the right data: everything else is moot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got past this by using

```
var size = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder (_reader.ReadInt32 ());
var udpTunnel = new UDPTunnel { packet = _reader.ReadBytes(size) };
```

Now I don't know why Deserializewithlengthprefix was not working because as I understand, these lines are doing the same thing.